# how to store image url in array format

Tags: reactjs

I have a set of images in a folder and now I want to store those images as an array format as shown below

```
    const slideImages = [
    '/assets/boatImage.jpg',
    '/assets/old.jpg',
    '/assets/vacations.jpg'
  ];
```

I cannot access those images though the path is correct. The folder structure is shown
[image]

I have tried the below code to access the path also but still not working

```
    const slideImages = [
    './assets/boatImage.jpg',
    './assets/old.jpg',
    './assets/vacations.jpg'
  ];
```

This is the `react` code

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Slide } from 'react-slideshow-image';
    import './style.css';

const slideImages = [
    './assets/boatImage.jpg',
    './assets/old.jpg',
    './assets/vacations.jpg'
  ];

  const properties = {
    duration: 5000,
    transitionDuration: 500,
    infinite: true,
    indicators: true,
    arrows: true,
    onChange: (oldIndex, newIndex) => {
      console.log(`slide transition from ${oldIndex} to ${newIndex}`);
    }
  }

export const  Home = () => (
            <div className="slide-container">
                <Slide {...properties}>
                    <div className="each-slide">
                        <div style={{'backgroundImage': `url(${slideImages[0]})`}}>
                        <span>Slide 1</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="each-slide">
                        <div style={{'backgroundImage': `url(${slideImages[1]})`}}>
                        <span>Slide 2</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="each-slide">
                        <div style={{'backgroundImage': `url(${slideImages[2]})`}}>
                        <span>Slide 3</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </Slide>
            </div>
    );
```

How to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import then use

```
import image1 from './assets/boatImage.jpg';
import image2 from './assets/old.jpg';
import image3 from './assets/vacations.jpg';

...

const slideImages = [image1, image2, image3];
```

Or create an `index.js` file in your assets directory that does the import/export

index.js

```
import image1 from './assets/boatImage.jpg';
import image2 from './assets/old.jpg';
import image3 from './assets/vacations.jpg';

export default {
  image1,
  image2,
  image3,
}
```

in component

```
import { image1, image2, image3 } from './assets';

...

const slideImages = [image1, image2, image3];
```